# Tesseract not using path variable

Tags: linux, tesseract, tess4j

Why does my Tesseract instance require me to explicitly set my datapath, but doesn't want to read the environment variable?

Let me clarify: running the code

```
ITesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
String result = tesseract.doOCR(myImage);
```

Throws an error:

```
Error opening data file ./tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the 
parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
```

I already have set my environment variable, ie doing

```
echo $TESSDATA_PREFIX returns /usr/share/tessdata/
```

Now, setting the path variable explicitly in my code, ie:

```
Itesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
tesseract.setDatapath("/usr/share/tessdata/");
String result = tesseract.doOCR(myImage);
```

WORKS PERFECTLY. Why?
I'm using Manjaro 17.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library was initially designed to use the data files bundled in its `tessdata` folder. In your case, if you want to read from the standard `tessdata` directory, you would want to set datapath as follows:

`tesseract.setDatapath(System.getenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX"));`

Comment: System.getenv will just return the exact same string which I've already set, though it's not hardcoded.. But, my question revolves more around "why is the library unable to locate its own `share` library" without me having to explicitly tell it where to look?

Comment: By default, tess4j uses its local `tessdata` folder, not Tesseract's. It's not aware of the path defined by `TESSDATA_PREFIX` variable.